# How to delete a specific row of a dynamic table after prompting the user using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is code that I'm using to add specific input values that a user enters in a modal, to a table using JQuery, in each row a delete button `$('td:contains("delete")').html("<i class='far fa-trash-alt' id='btnDelete'></i>").addClass("text-center delete delete:hover")` is also generated, however I am struggling with actually deleting the desired row in the table.

```
if ($("#insert-image").val() !== '' && $("#insert-name").val() !== '' && $("#insert-surname").val() !== '') {
      var imagePrep = $("#insert-image").val().replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, 'images/');
      let row = '<tr> <td class="align-middle">' + "image" + '</td> <td class="align-middle">' + $("#insert-name").val() + '</td> <td class="align-middle">' + $("#insert-surname").val() + '</td> <td class="align-middle">' + "edit" + '</td> <td class="align-middle">' + "delete" + '</td> </tr>'
      $('tbody').append(row);

      $('td:contains("image")').html("<img src=" + imagePrep + " alt='selected-image' class='image' data-toggle='popover-hover'>");

      $('td:contains("edit")').html("<i class='fas fa-edit'></i>").addClass("text-center edit edit:hover").on('click', function() {});

      $('td:contains("delete")').html("<i class='far fa-trash-alt' id='btnDelete'></i>").addClass("text-center delete delete:hover").on('click', function() {
        $("#delete-modal").modal('show');
        $("#btnDeleteConfirmation").on('click', function() {
            $(this).parents('tr').remove();
            $("#delete-modal").modal('hide');
          });
      });
    }
  });
```

The HTML code for the table and delete modal is:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Image</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Surname</th>
            <th scope="col">Edit</th>
            <th scope="col">Delete</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbody">

        </tbody>
</table>

<div class="modal fade" id="delete-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Delete Confirmation</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          Are you sure you want to delete this item?
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" id="btnDeleteDismiss">No</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnDeleteConfirmation">Yes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

When the delete button of a specific row is clicked a modal `#delete-modal` is displayed which prompts the user to confirm if they want to delete the desired row, only if the user clicks yes on the modal `#btnDeleteConfirmation` should the row be deleted. My attempt of this is below but it doesn't actually delete anything and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
$('td:contains("delete")').html("<i class='far fa-trash-alt' id='btnDelete'></i>").addClass("text-center delete delete:hover").on('click', function() {
        $("#delete-modal").modal('show');
        $("#btnDeleteConfirmation").on('click', function() {
            $(this).parents('tr').remove();
            $("#delete-modal").modal('hide');
          });
      });
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: add the html file as well please

Comment: will do @AbdullahAbid

Comment: is that fine @AbdullahAbid

Comment: yeah,that should do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are taking the **this** reference wrong. ***btnDeleteConfirmation*** doesnot have a parent tr hence its not working. What you need is to store the this reference of this line.

```
$('td:contains("delete")').html("<i class='far fa-trash-alt' id='btnDelete'></i>").addClass("text-center delete delete:hover").on('click', function() {
let deleteRef = this;
```

Then when you pass it with parent('tr').remove(), it shall work!